# Elixir not altering table in database migration

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've a table called Leads. It stores items such as name, quote_amount, lead_source_id and specifications.

My current update method:

```
 def update(conn, %{"id" => _id, "data" => data} = params, user) do

#data has structure like this: data["attributes"][value_to be stored]
#Example: data["attributes"]["specifications"] for specifications value
 

    lead =
      Lead.leads(user)
      |> Lead.with_id(params)
      |> Repo.one!()

    attrs = JaSerializer.Params.to_attributes(data)
    attrs = conversion_of_company_id_param_if_necessary(attrs, Map.get(attrs, "company_id"), lead)

    changeset = Lead.changeset(lead, attrs, user)

    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, lead} ->
        lead = Repo.get_by(Lead, id: lead.id) |> Repo.preload([:zipcode])
        render(conn, "show.json-api", data: lead)

      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(PortalApi.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

```
  schema "leads" do
    field(:first_name, :string)
    field(:last_name, :string)
    field(:email, :string)
    field(:next_step, :string)
    field(:activity_date, :date)
    field(:phone, :string)
    field(:quote_number, :string)
    field(:quote_amount, :integer)
    field(:po_number, :string)
    field(:po_amount, :integer)
    field(:closed_reason, :string)
    field(:specifications,:string)
    field(:zip, :string, virtual: true)
    field(:local_dealer, :boolean, default: false)
    field(:claimed, :boolean, default: false)
    field(:state, :string, default: "new")
    field(:message, :string)
    field(:uuid, :string)
    field(:reference_number, :string)
    field(:business_name, :string)
    field(:project_reference, :string)
    field(:quotable, :boolean, default: false)
    field(:lead_url, :string)
    field(:lead_details, :string)
    field(:details, :map)
    field(:printed, :boolean, default: false)

    belongs_to(:internal_rep, PortalApi.User)
    belongs_to(:external_rep, PortalApi.User)
    belongs_to(:company, PortalApi.Company)
    belongs_to(:proposed_company, PortalApi.Company)
    belongs_to(:lead_source, PortalApi.LeadSource)
    belongs_to(:zipcode, PortalApi.Zipcode, on_replace: :nilify)
    belongs_to(:quote_request, PortalApi.QuoteRequest)
    has_many(:attachments, PortalApi.Attachment)
    has_many(:activity_logs, PortalApi.ActivityLog)
    has_many(:notes, PortalApi.Note)
    timestamps()
  end
```

Migration of specifications table:

```
 def change do
    alter table(:leads) do
      add :specifications, :string
    end
  end
```

This update seem to update everything normally except that specification.
I've tried checking everything from model, to migrations and controllers, but it just doesn't seem to store that column. I can assure you that Postgres table is fine and all required column exists.

What could be the issue? How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What does `Lead.changeset/3` look like? Are you casting the field?

Comment: Wild guess: blame `JaSerializer.Params.to_attributes/1`.

Comment: One of the lib was altering value in changeset. Thanks!